# Manage drupal 8 modules with composer and drush

Tags: module, composer-php, updates, drupal-8, drush

I'm newcomer in drupal management with composer. As it, I need to do updates on my D8 websites (migrated from D6).
And I get mismatched informations between drush and composer, like this:

```
$ composer outdated drupal/*
drupal/feeds                   3.0.0-alpha5 3.0.0-alpha6 Aggregates RSS/Atom/RDF feeds, imports CSV files and more.
drupal/migrate_tools           4.3.0        4.4.0        Tools to assist in developing and running migrations.

$ drush @sited8 pml --filter=feed
 --------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------------
  Package   Name                                     Status     Version
 --------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------------
  Feeds     Feeds (feeds)                            Disabled   8.x-3.0-alpha4

$ drush @sited8 pml --filter=migr
 -------------------------- --------------------------------------------- --
  Package                    Name                                 Status     Version
 -------------------------- ----------------------------------------------- 
  Migration                  Migrate Tools (migrate_tools)             Disabled   8.x-4.1
```

So what's the good way to proceed with disabled modules ? Do I need to delete them with composer ? Doesn't exist a similar status as "disabled" for composer ?

Thanks

EDIT: good practice fixed, but what about mismatched informations between drush and composer ?

EDIT2: another case of mismatched informations

```
composer outdated drupal/*
drupal/admin_toolbar          1.27.0       2.0.0        Provides a drop-down menu interface to the core Drupal Toolbar.
drupal/better_exposed_filters 3.0.0-alpha6 4.0.0-alpha1 Provides advanced options (such as links, checkboxes, or jQueryUI widgets) for exposed Views elements.
drupal/webform                5.4.0        5.5.0        Enables the creation of webforms and questionnaires.
@ssh4:~/www/celony/sited8$ composer update drupal/admin_toolbar drupal/better_exposed_filters
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

More info: if update is mentionned as red I can run composer update, if it's in yellow, I do use composer require instead. Perhaps normal way ?
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/271204/15055

Comment: Thanks for this link. This is the right way : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/271211/8753

Comment: Yup that's why I edited my answer.